# Is there any way to tell if an event handler was triggered with code in jQuery without custom flags?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Consider this jQuery code:

```
$('button#my').click(function(event) {
    alert('hello');
});

$('button#my').click();
```

Obviously, this will bring up an alert window.

However, can I tell, with jQuery only, if that event handler was triggered with code or if the user clicked it (without ugly flag checking, e.g. `var userClicked = true`).

I thought there would be a property of `event`, but I couldn't figure it out.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check [`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/), it'll be `undefined` for the [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) (or other trigger) calls...for example:

```
$('button#my').click(function(event) {
    if(event.which) {
        alert("User click");
    } else {
        alert("triggered click");
    }
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/z9Q9G/).

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it out and there are many differences between them; have Firebug and try `$("button#my").click(console.log)` and you'll see the event logged when you click or `click()`. One is `event.currentTarget` which is the element when clicked, or `document` when `click()`ed (may be subject to change based on the scope it's called in, experiment). There are all sorts of other differences too - `(offset|client|layer)[XY]` are all set for click but not `click()`, and more.

(Edit: as Nick says, `event.which` is another; it's 1 for click and not defined for `click()`.)

Answer (score 1):

Late answer. Nick's answer would work, but you can do it in a little more explicit manner.

You can define your `.click()` with additional parameters, and pass those parameters by using `.trigger('click')` instead of `.click()`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/jWFAn/

```
// Passed via .trigger() ----------------v
$('button#my').click(function(event, wasManual) {
    if( wasManual ) {
        alert('triggered in code');
    } else {
        alert('triggered by mouse');
    }
});

  // Array of additional args------v
$('button#my').trigger( 'click', [true] );
```

This way it is using an explicit feature of jQuery in its supported manner.